# Trying to send data Python CAN

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I am using the python can library. I am running the following example code but can not get it to work

```
from __future__ import print_function

import can

def send_one():

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0', bitrate=250000)

msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xc0ffee,
                  data=[0, 25, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1],
                  is_extended_id=True)

try:
    bus.send(msg)
    print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
except can.CanError:
    print("Message NOT sent")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_one()
```

Here is the error message:

`OSError: [WinError 10047] An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used`

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I am completely new to using CAN to receive and send data. My current set up for testing this out is as follow:

Laptop -> USB Wire -> CANable Adapter -> CAN Line -> CANable Adapter -> USB Wire -> RaspberryPi

I also can't seem to find any documentation that has clear and concise examples. Thank you to all of those who reply in advance.

Link To Docs: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-can/develop/python-can.pdf

Comment: Is this code running on your Laptop or on the RaspberryPi? Is it running Windows (the error message imples that)? If so, `socketcan` is not available on windows. Which CAN adapter are you using?

Comment: @M.Spiller I am trying to run it on my laptop which is running Windows. I am using the CANable adapter from canable.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you are trying to use the socketcan interface, which is not available on Windows.

Your CANable adapter provides a serial interface. Try the following line:

```
bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='serial', channel='COM1', bitrate=250000)
```

Maybe you have to use a different COM-port-number instead of `COM1`

Check the python-can documentation chapter `CAN over serial` for more details.

Comment: I am using the COM1 port, but am getting an error.    `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM1'`

Comment: Is this the complete error message? Normally there should be an explanation, why the port could not be opened. Something like _access denied_ or so.
Are any other applications running, that access this port? If so, close them.
Also, try to run your python script as administrator.

Comment: This is the more complete message: `in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM8': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)` I tried running it as an admin but have no luck. Do I have to open the port manually with Python's serial library?

Comment: No, you don't. The error message says `COM8`. What about when running with `COM1`, which you claim to use. Same error message?

Comment: Yes, same error... only changed it to COM8 after COM1 failed.

Comment: Then the device is not really connected. Are you able to use it with another application? Check window's device manager whether you see it there. Do you have the drivers installed?

Comment: Turns out, I was using the wrong COM# ... changed it to COM4 and it was able to send data (or at least that's what it printed to the console). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Posted another question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133228/trying-to-receive-data-over-python-can